# Go compilation for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, go, compiler-errors

I've been working on this problem for a whole day and very stuck. I'd love help.

I am trying to compile a C/Go code to run in my iOS swift app. The library compiles fine for normal amd64 architecture.

To do the compilation I start with this compilation step which generate a static .a archive.

> GOOS=ios GOARCH=arm64 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=$(go env
> GOROOT)/misc/ios/clangwrap.sh go build -ldflags -w -v -tags ios -o
> "storj_uplink-arm64.a" -buildmode=c-archive

The next step after I use a scrub conversion to a dylib

> xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch arm64 -fpic -shared -Wl,-all_load
> storj_uplink-arm64.a  -framework Corefoundation -o libuplinkc.dylib

In Xcode, I drag the dependency to the copy files build phase. From Swift, I check various symbol addresses that I need and I can confirm beyond that step. However when the actual binary is running, I receive a series of runtime errors.

> dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
> DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib

In lldb debugger, this message is given with a Thread 12 signal SIGILL error.

```
libuplinkc.dylib`golang.org/x/sys/cpu.getisar0:
->  0x10c7a36f0 <+0>:  mrs    x0, ID_AA64ISAR0_EL1
    0x10c7a36f4 <+4>:  str    x0, [sp, #0x8]
    0x10c7a36f8 <+8>:  ret    
    0x10c7a36fc <+12>: udf    #0x0
```

Based on these errors and steps, I believe this has to do with the Go build process, but it's not clear what is breaking. In case this helps, I'm using the Storj uplink-c to Swift bindings ([relevant ticket here](https://github.com/storj-thirdparty/uplink-swift/issues/5)). People seem pretty convinced the C library is fine and suggested I go to the Go community for more debugging.

Comment: Running on device (arm64) or simulator (M1-arm64 or intel) ?

Comment: Running on iPhone 13

Comment: Found this [page](https://rogchap.com/2020/09/14/running-go-code-on-ios-and-android/) which may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gomobile` to build a native library for iOS and call your go code from your iOS app.
https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile#hdr-Build_a_library_for_Android_and_iOS